# checking if it is windows or unix before creating a directory in C++

Tags: c++, operating-system

I wrote this piece of code to check if a directory exists in both Windows and Unix, but I'm not sure whether it is correct:

```
int writeFiles(std::string location)
{

        // USED TO FILE SYSTEM OPERATION
        struct stat st;
        // DEFINE THE mode WHICH THE FILE WILL BE CREATED
        const char * mode = "w+b";
        /* local curl variable */

        // CHECK IF THE DIRECTORY TO WHERE THE FILE ARE GOING EXIST
        // IF NOT, CREATE IT
        if(stat(location.c_str(), &st) != 0){
                #ifndef (defined  _WIN32 || defined __WIN64)    /* WIN32 SYSTEM */
                if (!CreateDirectory(location.c_str(), NULL)){
                        std::string msg("The location directory did not exists, can't be created\n");
                        throw std::runtime_error(msg);
                }
                #elif defined __unix__          /* in the case of unix system */
                if(mkdir(location.c_str(), S_IRWXU) != 0){
                        std::string msg("The dest_loc directory did not exist, can't be created\n");
                        throw std::runtime_error(msg);
                }
                #endif

 ... more code down here.
```

`location` is the path to where the files are supposed to copied. However, before I start copying the files, I have to check whether the directory exists or not, for both Windows and Linux. Could someone please give me some input on that problem?
Thanks

Comment: Which bit are you unsure of ?

Comment: @hmjd The #ifndef part ... I'm not sure if it will handle the both cases (Windows and Unix)

Comment: have you tried using boost.filesystem?

Comment: `#ifndef` should just be `#if`

Comment: WIN32 is defined for WIN64 targets also...

Comment: @PaulR If I tell you were right on the money, would you believe? Could you make your question an answer?

Comment: @philippe: sure - no problem - have converted comment to answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change:

```
            #ifndef (defined  _WIN32 || defined __WIN64)    /* WIN32 SYSTEM */
```

to:

```
            #if (defined _WIN32 || defined __WIN64)    /* WIN32 SYSTEM */
```

This tests whether either `_WIN32` or `__WIN64` is defined and then uses the WINAPI code if that is the case.

You could probably also change:

```
            #elif defined __unix__          /* in the case of unix system */
```

to just:

```
            #else          /* in the case of non-Windows system */
```

since most non-Windows OS are likely to have POSIX-ish APIs for `mkdir` etc, and you currently don't have any other OS-specific code.

Answer (score 4):

The preprocessor directives (see list of [Microsoft Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) I would write as:

```
#ifdef _WIN32

#else

// Assume UNIX system,
// depending on what you are compiling your code on,
// by that I mean you only building on Windows or UNIX
// (Linux, Solaris, etc) and not on Mac or other.
#endif
```

The [`CreateDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will fail (return `FALSE`) if the directory already exists but will set the last error to `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`. Change your use of `CreateDirectory()` to handle this correctly:

```
if (!CreateDirectory(location.c_str(), NULL) &&
    ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS != GetLastError())
{
    // Error message more useful if you include last error code.
    std::ostringstream err;
    err << "CreateDirectory() failure on "
        << location
        << ", last-error="
        << GetLastError();

    throw std::runtime_exception(err.str());
}
```

Having said that, if you have access to boost consider using the [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library.

Comment: @djechlin, `_WIN32` is defined on 64-bit. And it is `_WIN32`, not `__WIN32`.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to write cross-platform code that interacts with the filesystem, I would use a cross-platform filesystem API, like [Boost FileSystem](http://boost.sourceforge.net/libs/filesystem/doc/).

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that Windows has `stat()`, why can't you also just use `mkdir()`?

But really, on Windows you can call `CreateDirectory` unconditionally (no preceding `stat` call) and check whether `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.

Also, `std::string` is a match for the ANSI function, `CreateDirectoryA`.  Using the `CreateDirectory` macro leaves you open to Unicode mismatch.